# Inserting hyperlink in CV

Tags: hyperref, links, overleaf

I am making a CV on Overleaf and  and under one section I want to insert a hyperlink. But when I try out  \hyperref it gives an error as `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`

Here's the following I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

Here's a link to \href{http://twitter.com/home}{Twitter}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget `\begin{document}`???

Answer (score 1):

With proper opening it works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} % here - PS

Here's a link to \href{http://twitter.com/home}{Twitter}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the first time I am using Latex so I don't know much. I used your code but stil it gives the error. Is it because at the very beginning I have already included `\begin{document}`. So in the middle before I use the above code do I  have to do something like `\end{document}`

Comment: `\begin{document}` before `\documentclass`? So please try to put in your question such MWE that gives the error.

Comment: At the beginning I have `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} ` then `\begin{document}` and after this some other content. Then I want to include the hyper link. But when I used the above code it gives an error as `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.110 \documentclass
                    {article}`

Comment: @clarkson So the source of error is the second `\documentclass`!

Comment: @ Przemysław Scherwentke What can I do here? I can't use it without the second `\documentclass`. If I write as `\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} % here - PS

Here's a link to \href{http://twitter.com/home}{Twitter}.
\end{document}` again it gives the same error

Comment: @clarkson I highly recommend you get a book or good tutorial on the very basics on LaTeX. no offense, but you clearly lack the fundamental understanding on how it works. such as: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos433/Latex/latex-guide.pdf